# Some properties of $\sigma,$ a $10-cycle.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

May I verify if my proofs to the b/m claims are correct? Thank you.

Let $\sigma$ be a $10-$cycle.

Claim I:  $\sigma^5$ is a product of $5$ disjoint $2-$cycles.

Proof:  Let $\sigma = (i_1...i_{10}).$  Since $o(\sigma) = 10,$ we have $o(\sigma^5) = 2.$ By Disjoint cycle product theorem, $\sigma^5= \sigma_1\sigma_2...\sigma_r,$ where $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ are disjoint whenever $i\neq j.$  Note that $\sigma^5 (i_j) \neq i_j, \forall i_j \in\{i_1,...,i_{10}\}.$

By Permutation order calculation theorem , $2= lcm(s_1,...,s_r),$ where $s_i =$ length of $\sigma_i.$ $\implies s_i = 2, \forall i \in \{1,...,r\}.$

Suppose $r>5.$ Then $\exists i,j \in \{1,...,r\}$ such that $\sigma_i, \sigma_j$ are not disjoint.  (Contradiction).

Suppose $r<5.$ Then $\exists i_m \in \{i_1,...,i_{10}\}$ such that $\sigma^5(i_m) = i_m.$ (Contradiction).

i.e. $r=5.$

Claim II: $\sigma^n$ is a product of $2$ disjoint $5-$ cycles, for $n=2,4,6,8.$

Proof: Clearly, $o(\sigma^n) =5,$ for $n=2,4,6,8.$ Let $\sigma =(k_1 ... k_{10}).$Let  $\sigma^n = \sigma_1\sigma_2...\sigma_q,$  where $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ are disjoint whenever $i\neq j.$  Note that $\sigma^n (k_j) \neq k_j, \forall k_j \in\{k_1,...,k_{10}\}.$

By Permutation order calculation theorem, $5 = lcm(s_1,...,s_q),$ where $s_i =$ length of $\sigma_i.$
$\implies s_i = 5, \forall i \in \{1,...,q\}$

$\implies q = 2.$ (proof is similar to claim I 's).

Claim III: $\sigma^n $ is a $10-$cycle for $n=3,7,9.$

Proof: Let $\sigma =(i_1 ... i_{10}).$ Clearly, $o(\sigma^n) = 10.$ Let $\sigma^n = \sigma_1\sigma_2...\sigma_m,$ where $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ are disjoint whenever $i\neq j.$ 
Then, $10 = lcm(s_1,...,s_m),$ where $s_i =$length of $\sigma_i.$.

Suppose $\forall i\in \{1,...,m\} [ s_i \in \{2,5\} \wedge \exists j,k \in \{1,...,m\}: s_i = 5, s_j = 2].$ Since $\sigma$ is disjoint product, $\exists i_r \in \{i_1,...,i_{10}\}$ such that $\sigma^n (i_r) = i_r.$ (Contradiction)

i.e. $m= 1.$